# Calculating the bouncing ball bounce height while on platforms

Tags: physics, mathematics, physics-engine

I tried to calculate the bounce height for the bouncing ball however it ends up shaking against the moving platform after it finishes bouncing. `grav_val` in this case is 0.1872 to prevent it to shake from normal surfaces after it finishes bouncing as a temporary fix.

```
yspeed = -max(0,(rounding(abs((yspeed + platform) / 2) - (grav_val) , 0.1)) + platform);
```

What the rounding function does is just rounds by a factor of whatever the second argument's number is.

```
return (input / factor) * factor
```

Finally, `platform` is the vertical speed of the platform that moves up, so let's hypothetically say it's in the speed of two for example:

```
platform = 2;
```

So, basically I want it to fully diminish until it hits to zero regardless of `yspeed` adding itself because it does right now due to gravity and the platforms. Rewrites or new methods would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this is considered a bump but i still am stuck at this

however i got into a new method done:

 yspeed = -((abs(yspeed) / 2));
 if (abs(yspeed) < 0.5) 
  yspeed = 0;

but how could i take moving platforms into account when it comes to bouncing, that's all I'm asking.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. In this case, I would recommend editing your question to include the revised formula & the information about how it's not properly accounting for moving platforms (i.e. what happens versus what you want).